# O que acontece com os votos de um candidato que desista de concorrer?

Tags: debate, eleição

Já temos uma desistências nas primárias. No caso da próxima etapa (as finais), se alguém desistir, o que ocorre com os votos? São perdidos? E contatos como não-presentes? Ou a pessoa se houver tempo terá chance de votar em outros?

Comment: Eu suponho que - como todo usuário tem a opção de mudar o seu voto quantas vezes quiser até que a eleição acabe - ele terá sim a chance de votar em outros. Não sei quanto ao caso de sobrar votos em um candidato desistente, contudo (embora [o processo de contagem de votos](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77541/177950) me pareça dar conta disso também).

Comment: Já agora e o que acontece se um candidato desista e eu tiver escolhido ele com 1ª opção e não escolher outra? O que acontece ao 2º e 3º em quem votei?